# How can I collect the NeoGate tech point?

Tags: watch-dogs-legion

I am trying to get the tech point located in a vent at the NeoGate building just north east of Angel tube station in the north eastern part of the map.

[image: NeoGate building map location]

It's located near a vent grate, but I do not get a prompt to pick it up. As usually there is a prompt to press <kbd>y</kbd> button to collect it.

[image: NeoGate tech point no prompt]

Is this tech point bugged? How can I reset the buildings state in order to try again?

Answer (score -1):

I used a normal spider drone to pick it up. It looks live you have a flying drone I think. So you need a spider drone. Flying drones can't pick up items as far as I know.

Comment: This is a spider drone. As you can see there is no prompt to pick it up

Comment: I believe I managed to pick it up.....perhaps it was bugged and you needed to restart the game? I've seen a handful of bugs in the game and many highly recurring ones.